# How can i get alias value from the where clause with mysql query?

Tags: mysql

How can i get the alias values from the where clause?

```
SELECT <DATA> FROM <TABLE> WHERE <CONDITION1> AS LABEL1,<CONDITION2> AS LABEL2;
```

Result would be,

```
<DATA>
<LABEL1>
```

Or

```
<DATA>
<LABEL2>
```

Any suggestion for me?

Comment: why you need alias for where condition?

Comment: for track the satisfied condition part.

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned in label1 and label2? Are you trying to return which condition was satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ALIAS` in the `WHERE` clause but instead you can have it in a `HAVING` clause.